# Migrate MOSS 2007 (Fab 40 Templates) to SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, 2019, migration, fab-40

I have a MOSS 2007 environment (with Fab 40 site templates) that I was planning to migrate (Content DB Approach or Sharegate) to SharePoint 2019 environment. We have read some articles that says install Fab 40 WSP's to SharePoint 14 as well as 15 hive folder for SharePoint 2013. Will that work for SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint 2019.

Also, give me a suggestion which is the best approach to migrate either Content DB or Sharegate.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

It´s high complexity question, but possible to migrate installing all wsp with compatibility level (for example , using [Install-SPSolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps) with `-CompatibilityLevel` parameter), but without upgrade the UI Experience (I don´t know if ShareGate 3rd party makes upgrade without upgrade UI Experience). But, I think, in some moment, you will need to discontinue the Fab40 (as you mentioned, from SharePoint 2013 to later do not have some templates that support Fab40).